# En laravel ¿Es necesario que las tablas tengas el campo de "created_at" como el de "updated_at"?

Tags: php, mysql

¿Hay alguna forma de que pueda crear esos **dos campos** desde mi consola y como podria hacerlo?

Debo aclarar que la base de datos me la pasaron ya creada, ahora tengo que implementarla en este framework

Comment: no son necesarias y claro que se pueden crear por separado

Answer (score 1):

Los campos `created_at` y `updated_at` son opcionales si no quieres usar por ejemplo la función de `soft delete` que tiene Laravel para hacer borrado lógico de datos, pero sobre todo depende de lo que estes resolviendo, tu propia lógica de negocio te va a indicar si requieres o no esos campos

Sin embargo si requieres que dichas columnas aparezcan en tu tabla, se puede hacer del modo siguiente, tendiendo en cuenta que:

1. Son campos de tipo `DATETIME`
2. Respeta la nomenclatura de los nombres de las columnas **created_at y updated_at**

Teniendo como base este ejemplo, te sugiero te guíes

Estructura original de la tabla de ejemplo

```
MariaDB [demon]> describe amigos;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| numero       | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| name         | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| username     | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| status_amigo | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id      | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Con la sentencia ALTER vamos a agregar la siguiente columna que sería created_at, usaremos AFTER para indicarle después de que columna la queremos

```
MariaDB [demon]> ALTER TABLE amigos ADD created_at DATETIME AFTER user_id;
```

Lo siguiente será repetir los pasos pero ahora para la columna updated_at igualmente con la sentencia AFTER para indicarle a donde la queremos

```
MariaDB [demon]> ALTER TABLE amigos ADD updated_at DATETIME AFTER created_at;
```

Teniendo como resultado final, lo siguiente

```
MariaDB [demo]> describe amigos;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| numero       | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| name         | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| username     | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| status_amigo | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id      | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```